# How to read Pig "detailed locations" log lines?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

When executing a Pig script, some of these logs are emited :

```
2014-10-29 16:07:03,658 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: TRACKED[155,10],null[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],TRACKED_USERS[156,16],null[-1,-1],HAS_CONV[163,11],HAS_CONV[164,11],null[-1,-1],REACHED[159,10],REACHED[160,10] C:  R:
```

I understand that all my aliases listed after the `M:` sections are mapper-based locations, `C:` should be combiners, and `R:` should be reducers.

How should I interpret the values between brackets, such as `159` and `10` in: `REACHED[159,10]` ? Do they provide me a hint about the input splits that are being processed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It provides information about the aliases of the Pig script in the form of `alias[line, offset]` and how they are related to the different stages of the translated MR job (M:map, C:combiner, R:reducer).
References:
[New features in Pig 0.11](http://www.slideshare.net/hortonworks/new-features-in-pig-011/18)
[Example testcase](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/test/org/apache/pig/newplan/logical/relational/TestLocationInPhysicalPlan.java)